# VeeValidate4. How to test custom field Component which uses useField?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vee-validate, vue-testing-library

I tried to test my custom input component. But I don't know how to do it right, because I didn't find any info how to test it.
The only thing I found was from this [Mocking Form and Field Contexts](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/testing/#mocking-form-and-field-contexts)

**My custom component:**

```js
<script setup>
import { useField } from 'vee-validate';
import { watch, toRef } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: undefined,
    default: undefined,
  },

  type: {
    type: String,
    default: 'text',
  },

  label: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

const { value, setValue, errorMessage } = useField(toRef(props, 'name'));

watch(
  () => value.value,
  (newValue) => {
    emit('update:modelValue', newValue);
  }
);

watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }
);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label v-if="props.label" :for="props.label">{{ props.label }}</label>

    <input
      :id="props.label"
      v-model="value"
      :name="props.name"
      :type="props.type"
      class="form-input"
    />

    <span v-if="errorMessage" class="form-error" role="alert">{{ errorMessage }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

**My test file:**

```js
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/vue';
import AppField from './AppField.vue';
import { FormContextKey, useForm } from 'vee-validate';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

const rednerField = ({ label, type, ...rest } = {}) => {
  const options = { props: { name: 'inputName', label, type }, ...rest };

  render(AppField, options);
};

const user = userEvent.setup();

const MockedForm = useForm({
  validationSchema: {
    inputName(value) {
      if (value && value.trim()) {
        return true;
      }

      return 'This is required';
    },
  },
});

describe('showing error', () => {
  it('show error if field is invalid', async () => {
    rednerField({ label: 'labelName', global: { provide: { [FormContextKey]: MockedForm } } });
    const input = screen.getByLabelText('labelName');

    user.type(input, ' ');

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByRole('alert')).toHaveTextContent('This is required');
    });
  });
});
```

This test works correctly, but there are warnings in the console:
[console log from jest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmJ3N.png)

Please tell me if this test is written correctly and how can I get rid of warnings or is this normal ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into this exact same issue on my project.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to do this myself. This issue may be 2 years old but the vee-validate documentation doesn't really explain how to deal with these issue so this might help the next person who runs into this problem.

I ended up making a helper function that extends the Component `setup()` so the `provide` within `useForm` will run in the right context. I hate to couple to the library like this but I wasn't able to get a mock form context working without it.

With this setup you should be able to get working tests against any expected `validationSchema`

#### Helper function

```
export function getExtendedComponent(
  inputComponent: ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>,
  options: { mockFormData: FormData }
): Component {
  return {
    ...inputComponent,
    setup(props, ctx) {
      let result = {};

      if (options.mockFormData) {
        const useFormResult = useForm(options.mockFormData);
        /** @ts-ignore non-problematic type differences */
        provide(FormContextKey, useFormResult);
      }

      if (inputComponent.setup) {
        const setupResult = inputComponent.setup(props, ctx);
        result = { ...result, ...setupResult };
      }

      return result;
    },
  };
}
```

#### Test file setup

```
const mockFormData = {
  validationSchema: {
    username(value: string) {
      if (value && value.trim()) {
        return true;
      }

      return "required";
    },
  },
};

const InputComponentWrapped: Component = getExtendedComponent(InputComponent, {
  mockFormData,
});
```